# IconUrl element fails to appear in Outlook Add-in on Desktop

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

For an Outlook Add-in, the IconURL (defined in the Manifest) appears OK when Outlook is running in the Web, but fails to appear for Outlook Desktop

Just in case this might be relevant: the M/S documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/iconurl?view=common-js-preview is not totally clear: "For content and task pane apps, the image specified must be 32 x 32 pixels. For mail apps, the image resolution must be 64 x 64 pixels" - is an Outlook Add-in a "mail app"? Presumably, as Manifest validation fails on a 32 x 32 pixel image - but is fine with 64 x 64

Screenshots below of Web, with icon, and Desktop, without, in that order, plus part of Manifest

[image]
[image]

```
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="TeamsAssist Help" />
  <Description DefaultValue="TeamsAssist Notifications Help"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/TeamsAssistLogo64x64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Images/TeamsAssistLogo128x128.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> is an Outlook Add-in a "mail app"?

Yes, it is. Outlook add-ins stand separately unlike other Office add-ins. See [Microsoft Office - Exploring the JavaScript API for Office: Mail Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/june/microsoft-office-exploring-the-javascript-api-for-office-mail-apps) for more information.

Comment: Well that confirms why only a 64x64 pixel icon is acceptable, but why does the icon appear only in the Outlook Web and not in Outlook Desktop?

Comment: Hi @JohnD, where in Outlook desktop are you expecting to see the icon? Would you also be able to provide screenshots of Desktop vs Web and your manifest? Thanks

Comment: Please see edits above including image clips & Manifest  - relevant bit of it ...

Answer (score 0):

Currently we do not use the icon in the taskbar title in Win32. This is one of the differences between the two clients.

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered when we go through our planning process.

Github Label: “Type: product feature request”

https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions